# install influxdb in a docker with non standard port

Tags: docker, influxdb, telegraf

I am new in dockers and I need some help please. 
I am trying to install TICK in docker. Influxdb, Kapacitor and Chronograf will be installed in dockers but telegraf will be installed in each machine that will be necessary. 
Port 8086 in my host is in use, so I will use 8087 for influxdb. Is it posible to configure influxdb dokcer with -p 8087:8086? If so, which port should I configure in conf files?
Docker compose file will be:

```
version: '3'

networks:
    TICK_network:

services:

influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    networks:
        TICK_network:
    ports:
        - "8087:8086"
        - "8083:8083"
    expose:
        - "8087"
        - "8083"
    hostname: influxdb
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
        - /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

kapacitor:
    image: kapacitor
    container_name: kapacitor
    networks:
        TICK_network:
    links:
        - influxdb
    ports:
        - "9092:9092"
    expose:
        - "9092"
    hostname: kapacitor
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/kapacitor:/var/lib/kapacitor
        - /etc/kapacitor/kapacitor.conf:/etc/kapacitor/kapacitor.conf:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

chronograf:
    image: chronograf
    container_name: chronograf
    networks:
        TICK_network:
    links:
        - influxdb
        - kapacitor
    ports:
        - "8888:8888"
    expose:
        - "8888"
    hostname: chronograf
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/chronograf:/var/lib/chronograf
    restart: unless-stopped
```

influxdb.conf is edited to point to port 8087

```
[http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8087"
  auth-enabled = true
```

Kapacitor.conf and telegraf.conf are also pointing to port 8087. 
But I am receiving following errors:

Telegraf log:

```
W! [outputs.influxdb] when writing to [http://localhost:8087]: database "telegraf" creation failed: Post http://localhost:8087/query: EOF
E! [outputs.influxdb] when writing to [http://localhost:8087]: Post http://localhost:8087/write?db=tick: EOF
E! [agent] Error writing to outputs.influxdb: could not write any address
```

kapacitor log:

```
vl=error msg="encountered error" service=run err="open server: open service *influxdb.Service: failed to link subscription on startup: authorization failed"
run: open server: open service *influxdb.Service: failed to link subscription on startup: authorization failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct if you want to access those services from outside the Docker network, that is from the host access to `localhost:8087` for example.

However, this is not correct in your case. As you are using `docker-compose`, all the services are in the same network, and therefore, you need to attack the port in which the influx is listening **in** the Docker network (the right-side port), that is, `8086`.

But, even if you do so, it will still not work. Why? Because you are trying to access `localhost` from the Telegraf container. You need to configure the access to influx as `influxdb:8086`, not as `localhost:8087`. `influxdb` here is the name of the container, if for example you name it `ailb90`, then it would be `ailb90:8086`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. But telegraf is not installed in a container. This is why I access to database using `urls = ["http://localhost:8087"]`.

In the other hand, kapacitor is installed in a docker container. The conexion to influxdb is made using the string `urls=["https://influxdb:8087"]`. If I cinfigure kapacitor in port 8086 it gives a connexion error (I think it is because influxdb.conf is pointing to port 8087):

```
lvl=error msg="failed to connect to InfluxDB, retrying..." service=influxdb cluster=default err="Get http://influxdb:8086/ping: dial tcp 172.0.0.2:8086: connect: connection refused"
```